# GKE - How to expose pod for cross-cluster communication with MCS

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka, google-kubernetes-engine, redpanda

In Google Cloud Platform, my goal is to have one cluster with a message queue and a pod to consume these in another cluster with MCS (Multi Cluster Service). When trying this out with only *one* cluster it went fairly smooth. I used the container name with the port number as the endpoint to connect to the redpanda message queue like this:

[image]

Now I want to do this between two clusters, but I'm having trouble configuring stuff right. This is my setup:

[image]

I followed [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/multi-cluster-services) to set the clusters up which seemed to work (hard to tell, but no errors), and the redpanda application inside the pod is configured to be on `localhost:9092`. Unfortunately, I'm getting a Connection Error when running the consumer on `my-service-export.my-ns.svc.clusterset.local:9092`.

Is it correct to expose the pod with the message queue on its localhost?

Are there ways I can debug or test the connection between pods easier?

Comment: Use ping and netcat to test connectivity. Once that works, move onto kcat to test Kafka listeners

Answer (score 1):

Ok, got it working. I obviously misread the setup at one point and had to re-do some stuff to get it working.

Also, the `my-service-export` should probably have the same name as the service you want to export, in my case `redpanda`.

A helpful tool to check the connection without running up a consumer is the simple `dnsutils` image. Use this deployment file and change the namespace to `my-ns`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: dnsutils
  namespace: my-ns # <----
spec:
  containers:
    - name: dnsutils
      image: k8s.gcr.io/e2e-test-images/jessie-dnsutils:1.3
      command:
        - sleep
        - "3600"
      imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  restartPolicy: Always
```

Then spin it up with `apply`, `exec` into it, then run `host my-service-export.my-ns.svc.clusterset.local`. If you get an IP back you are probably good.